# Strange WordPress index.php inside all the links

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I installed several WordPress servers before but this is the first time I encounter this issue, where all the links must have 'index.php' in the URL (i.e. instead of test.com/games it is test.com/index.php/games), I searched for several issues and there was a similar thread here: [Remove index.php from Wordpress URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48711944/remove-index-php-from-wordpress-urls) but it didn't give an answer to my problem

HYG some details from my server:

1) `mod_rewrite` is enabled

2) I have a virtual host configuration:

```
# domain name: test.com 
# public: /var/www/test.com 
# Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases 
ServerAdmin test@gmail.com 
ServerName test.com 
ServerAlias www.test.com 
# Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located) 
# DirectoryIndex index.php 
DocumentRoot /var/www/test.com 
# Custom log file locations 
LogLevel warn 
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-test.com.log 
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-test.com.log combined
```

3) And I have .htaccess as follows:

```
Options FollowSymLinks 
AllowOverride All
# BEGIN WordPress 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
# END WordPress
```

4) The WordPress directory permissions are `rwsr_xr_x` and its files are `rwx_r__r__ (owner www-data:www-data)`

5) Permalinks configuration is `/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`

I am not familiar with the .htaccess format so perhaps it needs to be adjusted some how, please advise?

Comment: `DirectoryIndex index.php` why is it commented out?

Comment: It was not commented out but I commented it out while trying to resolve the issue

Comment: I returned it back now but the same issue still exists

Comment: I noticed that changing the permalinks configuration doesn't affect .htaccess so I changed its permissions temporary to 777 but again this didn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

The normal wordpress `.htaccess` is a follows

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] //you aren't escaping in your example
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks but changing it as mentioned doesn't resolve the issue, actually this was the format before I started looking for a resolution, do you think I should check something else?

Comment: what is the value of home_url in the wp_options table?

Comment: Both siteurl and home values are the domain name (i.e. http://test.com)

Comment: this might be a silly one but did you refresh the permalinks after the changes?

Comment: Yes every time I made a change I tried to change the permalinks and see the output